# how Javascript call to a function of a external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i made a html page with this coding

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../a.js">
var u=document.URL; var i='t4527878445'; m_web(u,i);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**In a.js i have this code**

```
function m_web(u,i) {
    alert('l');
    alert('u');
}
```

but my webpage is unable to call this function which is coded in an external file. i am not getting any alert with this. i don't know what is problem. plz tell me simple solution for this.
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz write your code like below

```
<script src="../a.js"></script> </script>
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ first close script tag of linked js file
<script type="text/javascript">// then call your inline jscode
var u=document.URL; var i='t4527878445'; m_web(u,i);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A single `<script>` tag can link to an external resource using the `src` attribute OR contain inline JavaScript code, but it can't do both at the same time. If you specify a `src` attribute any content between the `<script src="foo.js">` tag and the `</script>` tag is ignored.

Since you want to load the external JS file, and then execute some JavaScript code, you'll need two separate tags to do so:

```
<script src="../a.js"></script>
<script>
    // your code
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

you are not closing script tag

```
<script src="../a.js"></script>
                       ^//added closing script tag
<script>
var u=document.URL; var i='t4527878445'; m_web(u,i);
</script>
```

---

to alert what you pass use

```
function m_web(u,i) {
    alert(i);
    alert(u);
}
```